# Querying data from database with vb6 and ms access with adodb

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I want to select and view my data in the database, but it’s proving to be a challenge. Any advice on where I could be missing it? If I run this code even when the select criteria is met, it always returns search failed. Any help?

```
If txtSun.Text = "SUN" Then
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSql As String
    sSql = "SELECT * FROM SundryProduct WHERE ProdCont='" & txt_con_code.Text & "'"
    rst.Open sSql, Cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, , adCmdText
    'rst.Open "SELECT * FROM SundryProduct WHERE ProdCont='" & txt_con_code.Text & "' ", Cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, , adCmdText
    If rst.EOF Then
    MsgBox ("SEARCH FAILED")
    Else
    MsgBox ("QUANTITY ORDERED  " & rst!QuantityOrdered & vbCrLf & "   My Load Number is   " & rst!LoadNumber)
    End If
End If
```

I am trying to find out if there is a record with a matching `ProdCont` value in the database, but since I was still trying to make this code work in the first place I have only put messageboxes in the code. I have even tried putting in an actual value that I know exists in the database but it still returns the search failed messagebox even though I know the value exists in the database.

Comment: Is this a SQL Server backend, or MS Access? Either way, can you get your query to run successfully in the source database?

Comment: Can you post short but complete (as much as it is possible with VB6) program? http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If rst.EOF = True Then '----> here
  MsgBox ("SEARCH FAILED")
Else
  MsgBox ("QUANTITY ORDERED  " & rst!QuantityOrdered & vbCrLf & "   My Load Number is   " &  rst!LoadNumber)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you try to just run a simple query i.e. select * from SundryProduct?
I would start with that and build on it to eliminate the possibilty of coding/syntax causing the error message